# .htaccess regex not matching

Tags: regex, .htaccess, browser-cache

I am trying to setup my web server so that visitors can cache javascript files.  All my javascript files end in ".js" but the browser will sometimes append information onto the url like this ".js?a=1&test"

I am trying to create a FilesMatch line that will causes all .js files to be cached.  I have created the .htaccess file below but for some reason my .js files are being retrieved from the server each time  (according the Chrome's diagnostics).  Can someone tell me what is wrong with this .htaccess file?

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js)(\?.*)?$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

The response headers when retrieving a .js file are

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=604800, public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:5153
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Thu, 13 Jun 2013 16:50:35 GMT
ETag:"48b467f-4aee-4dea93003a0e6"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Last-Modified:Sat, 08 Jun 2013 19:02:23 GMT
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Is something else going on?  Do browsers always retrieve .js files regardless of cache settings?

Comment: I would add an expire header. Does the part after the question mark change on every call?

Comment: Yes - often a PHP session ID.